# How to search for a file in apk packages

Tags: package-management, alpine-linux, apk-tools

I would like to know, given a binary's name, which package I should install on Alpine Linux.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have three ways basically.

**First:**
The package should be installed and you need to specify the full path :

```
apk info --who-owns /path/to/the/file
```

**Second:** Use the [pkgs.alpinelinux.org](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents) website

**Third:** Use the api.alpinelinux.org API by filtering the json output.
For this you need a json parser like jq:

```
apk add jq
```

then use the API with the instructions provided [here](https://github.com/insteps/aport-api/blob/master/docs/api-json.md)

### UPDATE on 2022-04-07

I've released a tiny utility that allows to search via CLI what can be found on [pkgs.alpinelinux.org](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents) website: https://github.com/fcolista/apkfile

.: Francesco

Comment: `apk info` seems to be closer to `dpkg -S`. In my case I'm trying to answer the question "What package provides this binary that I know the name of", rather than where does this pre-existing file come from.

Comment: therefore, `apk info --who-owns /with/th/full/path` is the tool if you have the package installed, otherwise from a CLI is not possible. You should check [pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents] (https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents) website. You write the binary name there, and it returns the package that contains that binary.

Comment: Using `apk info --who-owns`, how do you do if you don't know the file's full path?

Comment: No, you can't as yet...sorry

Comment: why is --who-owns undocumented?

Comment: It's documented. 
Read better the output of  "apk info --help"

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the equivalent of Debian's `apt-file` for Alpine. Searching for that yields [apk-file](https://github.com/jfrazelle/apk-file).

> Basically apt-file but for alpine.

Comment: That's what I'm after. It appears that *apk-file* is not an alpine package, you can install it with `go get github.com/jessfraz/apk-file` (it happily runs on non alpine systems). The binary is likely static so can probably be copied into docker containers etc.

Comment: apt-file basically parses pkgs.alpinelinux.org website...so using a JSON decode as i wrote before would be better, since does not need bloated software to reach the same goal.

Comment: Indeed, you can see that with `-d` option. And it [doesn't strip whitespaces](https://github.com/genuinetools/apk-file/issues/7). And for some reason with `--arch` it [doesn't display all the results](https://github.com/genuinetools/apk-file/issues/6).

Answer (score 3):

- Go to the official Alpine package-browsing website: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents
- In the `File` search bar, type the name of the file you are looking for

Example looking for file `telnet`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> given a binary's name, which package I should install on Alpine Linux.

The answer to the body of the question (not the same as the answer to the title of the question) is

`apk search -xqa cmd:vim` (where `vim` is the "binary's name"). In this case, there are two packages that provide that command.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for the question. Other solutions that propose to use apk-file or the alpine package website are also valid, but for the specific case of finding which package provides a specific command, this one is the most straight forward.