# Compile clang-tidy under Alpine Linux

Tags: package-management, compiling, alpine-linux, clang

I'm trying to make a Docker image for a CI pipeline, that needs to contain `clang-tidy` among other tools. The problem is that I can't find any package containing `clang-tidy` on the Alpine repos, which means that I am forced to compile it from source. Furthermore, I need only this tool, not the whole clang-tools suite.

Could you point me to any instructions on how to compile `clang-tidy` **only** under Alpine or to any compatible binaries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`clang-tidy` binary is available in the package `clang-extra-tools` in edge/main.

In order to have it installed,you should add the repository edge in your `/etc/apk/repositories`.

Please consider that `edge` is the development tree, therefore is not considered "stable", but the pacakge will be included in the next stable release.
In this page is explained better: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge

If you need to know how to find a specific file in the apk files (like in this case: which package contains `clang-tidy`?) , here you can find the solution:

[How to search for a file in apk packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307167/how-to-search-for-a-file-in-apk-packages/339584#339584)

.: Francesco