# Identify apk packages based on .PKGINFO depend entry

Tags: package-management, alpine-linux, apk-tools

I am interested in resolving apk package dependencies, ideally with a scripting language like python. Basically I want to be able to derive a dependency tree of a package, without the need to run on a alpine environment.

So far I am analyzing the .PKGINFO file and the dependencies. And fetch the other apk's using `http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/{arch}/{package}-{version}.apk`. However from the .PKGINFO depencd entries it is not possible so far. An excerpt of the [Python3 apk](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/python3) as example:

```
...
depend = so:libbz2.so.1
depend = so:libc.musl-s390x.so.1
depend = so:libcrypto.so.3
depend = so:libexpat.so.1
...
```

I know the post [How to search for a file in apk packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307167/how-to-search-for-a-file-in-apk-packages) and liked the idea of fetching information from the API https://api.alpinelinux.org, which isn't accessible anymore. Does someone know if a similar API is still running?

Is there any option other option to identify the package based on the .so file other than webscraping similar to [apkfile](https://github.com/fcolista/apkfile) as mentioned [above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307167/how-to-search-for-a-file-in-apk-packages)?

Or does anybody see a more suited way of deriving the dependency tree for a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any option other option to identify the package based on the .so file other than webscraping similar to apkfile as mentioned above?

Yes: do it the same way the `apk` command does. Download the package
index and parse it for dependency information. You can see the index
URLs when you run `apk update:

```
/ # apk update
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.16.2-161-gc2ac19fd6b [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main]
v3.16.2-163-g5c02fd86e3 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community]
OK: 17028 distinct packages available
```

These archives each contain an `APKINDEX` file that contains metadata
about all the packages in the corresponding repository. For example,
the `python3` entry looks like:

```
C:Q1MVpLjE5vLqKS+ZuzxsuVdc+Xe5A=
P:python3
V:3.10.5-r0
A:x86_64
S:14513129
I:49467392
T:A high-level scripting language
U:https://www.python.org/
L:PSF-2.0
o:python3
m:Natanael Copa <ncopa@alpinelinux.org>
t:1658764328
c:0b726d39d903e8ccb50cd92798afb35e6d7acce6
D:so:libbz2.so.1 so:libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 so:libcrypto.so.1.1 so:libexpat.so.1 so:libffi.so.8 so:libgdbm.so.6 so:libgdbm_compat.so.4 so:liblzma.so.5 so:libmpdec.so.3 so:libncursesw.so.6 so:libpanelw.so.6 so:libreadline.so.8 so:libsqlite3.so.0 so:libssl.so.1.1 so:libz.so.1
p:so:libpython3.10.so.1.0=1.0 so:libpython3.so=0 cmd:2to3-3.10=3.10.5-r0 cmd:2to3=3.10.5-r0 cmd:pydoc3.10=3.10.5-r0 cmd:pydoc3=3.10.5-r0 cmd:python3.10=3.10.5-r0 cmd:python3=3.10.5-r0
```

If we want to find the package that provides `so:libbz2.so.`, we would
search for an entry that lists that dependency on the `p:` line (for
`provides`).

That gets us:

```
C:Q1n7yd9034EvCCluHKeoNvh+KF4Iw=
P:libbz2
V:1.0.8-r1
A:x86_64
S:27057
I:73728
T:Shared library for bz2
U:http://sources.redhat.com/bzip2
L:bzip2-1.0.6
o:bzip2
m:Natanael Copa <ncopa@alpinelinux.org>
t:1586114186
c:596cd15e692776222d49da2700c6041b39ffbea9
D:so:libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
p:so:libbz2.so.1=1.0.8
```

So now we know that package (`P:`) libbz2 provides (`p:`)
`libbz2.so.1=1.0.8`.

---

You can find the APK index format documented [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Apk_spec#APKINDEX_Format).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the missing piece. Great help.